# Javascript: Is this a way to secure an authed route?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a login screen that lives at `/login`.  Upon entering a username and password then submitting it, it hits a Login api with the username and password.  If that is successful, a token is returned and is passed as an Auth header to another API endpoint is fired.  Once that passes, the user is technically verified and I redirect to `/account`.

On the `/account` page, I check the existence of a `login` cookie and a `subscription` cookie and if none of those are there, I redirect back to `/login` but that seems like a pretty simple thing to bypass by just creating 2 cookies with those names.

Is a good approach to call one of those API's (both? one?) at the very beginning and in the success callback for it, throw in all my rendering and code so that it only loads upon success of hitting that API -- and if it fails, I can redirect back to `/login` again.

*** this is my `/login` route ****

```
$('#login').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let result = $("#result");

  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '_______user/login',
     dataType: 'json',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     data: JSON.stringify({
        "userName": $("#email").val(),
        "password": $("#password").val(),
     }),
     success: function(data)
     {
        console.log(data.newToken);
        Cookies.set("login",data, { expires: 7 });

        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: '_______subscriptions/subInfo',
           headers: { 'Authorization': data.newToken },
           success: function(data)
           {    
             Cookies.set("subscription",data, { expires: 7 })
             window.location.href = "/pages/account";
           }                    
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
          console.log("FAILED ON STATUS");
        });

     }
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {

   });
 });
});
```

***  below is my `/account` route that you get redirected to if the above login is successful ***

```
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: '_______subscriptions/subInfo',
       headers: { 'Authorization': Cookies.get('login').newToken },
       success: function(data)
       {    
          *** RENDER EVERYTHING IN THE ACCOUNT PAGE ON SUCCESS
       }                    
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
      *** REDIRECT BACK TO LOGIN ROUTE IF FAILS***
    });
```

Comment: What file format at you using to check the login? You aren't just holding the login details in a `json` file or something client-side are you?

Comment: the login details are sent to the backend login API via the first ajax call.  A token is sent back if successful and stored in a cookie

Comment: So what back end language are you using or is it a third party API you are using?

Comment: the backend team uses Ruby